# Appending a row to an HTML table using multiple lines within the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, append

I want to add a row to an HTML table using JQuery. This statement works great:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#AddRow').click(function(){
    $('#Table1').find('tbody:last').append('<tr> <td>Hello World</td></tr>');
  });
});
```

This one doesn't:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#AddRow').click(function(){
    $('#Table1').find('tbody:last').append('<tr>
                                              <td>Hello World</td>
                                            </tr>');
  });
});
```

How can I make my append statement span multiple lines? I have a very large row of data cells that need to be added and smushing it together into one long line of code would be quite messy and confusing.

[I even made a fiddle for it as well.](http://jsfiddle.net/rcVKC/5/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string concatenation, so:

```
$('#Table1').find('tbody:last').append('<tr>' + 
                                           '<td>Hello World</td>' + 
                                       '</tr>');
 });
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcVKC/6/)

In ECMAScript6, the following will work using backticks:

```
$('#Table1').find('tbody:last').append(`<tr>  
                                            <td>Hello World</td> 
                                        </tr>`
                                       );
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! And I also found out about the "clone" function, so I will be switching between the two depending on complexity.